# Issues with searching within a binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, search, binary-tree

I am trying to add nodes to a binary tree, by searching the node to which the new node is supposed to be linked, sometimes my function works if I keep going to the left branch only, or to the right branch, if I have added nodes to the left one then trying to add nodes to the right, my function finds the right node but `return root` does not get triggered and recursion continues till the root is NULL;

I am using GCC on Ubuntu, if it has anything to do with it.

**Here is my code:**

```
tree* find_node(tree *root, unsigned int index){
    if(root==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else if(root->value==index){
        return root;

    }else if(root->value<=index){
        find_node(root->left, index);
    }else if(root->value>index){
        find_node(root->right, index);
    }
}

void create_node_link(tree **root, int value, int index, int link_type){
    tree *new_node=malloc(sizeof(tree));
    if(new_node!=NULL){
        new_node->left=NULL;
        new_node->right=NULL;
        new_node->value=value;
    }

    tree *position=find_node(*root, index);
    if(position==NULL){
        printf("NOT FOUND");
        getch();
        return;
    }

    if(link_type==1)
        link_left(position, new_node);
    else if(link_type==2)
        link_right(position, new_node);
    viz_tree(*root);
}
```

I just can't wrap my head around why `return root` doesn't terminate the function.

My tree is stored in the following way:

```
typedef struct my_tree tree; // in the header file
```

then in the header_name.c the struct looks like this:

```
struct my_tree{
unsigned int value;
tree *left;
tree *right;
```

};

**The root is initialized the following way:**

```
tree *root=create_node(1); //in the main program

tree *create_node(int value){ //function in header.c file
 tree* result=malloc(sizeof(tree));
  if(result!=NULL){
    result->left=NULL;
    result->right=NULL;
    result->value=value;
  }
return result;
}
```

Comment: For example I have extended the tree to the left with like 2 more levels, then If I add a node the right return does't get triggered even though the if statement gets triggered

Comment: Marius Iordan, save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Aside from the answer below, your comparison is backwards from how it's normally done: usually a smaller key goes on the left child branch.

Comment: Your compiler ought to be warning you that `find_node()` can fail to return a value, and you ought to be paying attention to it..

Comment: @MariusIordan: You should add your driver code and the test data that you use to the question. FWIW, your `create_node_link()` function looks a little strange to me: it seems that whether to insert in the left or right sub-tree should be implicit from the key value, not determined by a separate argument.

Comment: Side note on the struct: you don't need to typedef, just use `struct { . . . } my_tree;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have enabled all compiler warnings, it was just one insignificant warning.

Comment: @MariusIordan What warnings were enabled?  What was that _one insignificant warning_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I enabled all warnings using -Wall -Wextra flags. That one warning was comparison of int and unsigned int, which I have fixed.

Comment: @MariusIordan Note that -Wall does not enable all warnings.  For gcc, consider -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion and get "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"

Answer (score 1):

Because the recursice calls' return values never get used. The initial call can only return either `NULL` or `root`, but never the values in the recursive calls. You should return those to get that value in the initial call:

```c
tree* find_node(tree *root, unsigned int index) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else if (root->value == index) {
        return root;
    } else if (root->value < index) {  // can never be equal, so < over <=
        return find_node(root->left, index);
    }
    return find_node(root->right, index);  // no if needed
}
```

Comment: Still returns null when I extend the tree on the left for two levels then add a node to the right

Comment: Are you sure your tree is constructed properly?

Comment: I use typedef struct my_tree tree;
the struct stores: 
     unsigned int value;
     tree* left;
     tree* right;

Comment: I mean _constructed_, as in: are the values in your tree in the shape of a binary search tree, what are they and what is your input?

Comment: Yeah, I store them in the shape of a binary tree, the values on the left are always smaller, I add them one by one.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: I have added the graphviz example that my program outputs in the question (at the top)

Comment: So in the node with the value 1, you get 1 < 4, so you search left. This is not a binary search tree.

Comment: I have updated the input & the visualization, still having the same issue

Comment: I would like to point you to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) for the structuring of a binary search tree. All values *smaller* than the root are to the left, all values _bigger_ are to the right, in _relative_ and _absolute_ terms. Your example is **not** a binary search tree, and so it fails to find your values.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but still, If I recursively go through **all** of the tree it finds the desired value, but the function does not stop, meaning that `return root` does not work somehow.

Comment: The recursive call should follow one path, and one path only. Try printing each node and value as you traverse.

Comment: I have tried that in the following way `printf("%d - %d", root-> value, index);` index aka the desired value, when it is true that they are equal, I print "equal", which is in the same if statement as the return, but the recursion goes on untill the temporary root adress is NULL